# Check post_date in pre_get_posts

Tags: order, date, pre-get-posts

I want to change the order of a feed using pre_get_posts filter.  But I want to exclude dates older than today.  I see how one could do that if the date were in a meta key, but the date is in post_date.  How can I check post_date to only show posts later than today?  The site shows future post dates.

```
<?php 
function feedFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_feed) {
        $query->set('order','ASC');
    }
 
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','feedFilter');

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't really check `post_date` in `pre_get_posts`, because, well, the action fires *before* (`pre_`...) the posts have actually been fetched (...`get_posts`). :)

But, you *can* use `$query->set()` to *add date parameters* to the query. This is taken from [an example in the **`WP_Query()`** Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters):

```
<?php
function wpse54142_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $today = getdate();
        $query->set( 'year', $today['year'] );
        $query->set( 'monthnum', $today['mon'] );
        $query->set( 'day', $today['mday'] );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse54142_filter_pre_get_posts' );
?>
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but this only shows posts *on that day*, not into the future *from that day*.

Comment: From the OP: "*But I want to exclude dates older than today.*". Why would an RSS feed ever need to show **future** posts?

Comment: I don't know, but also from the OP: "*The site shows future post dates*"

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using a `posts_where` filter:

```
function wpa54142_feed_filter( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_feed ) {
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpa54142_filter_where' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa54142_feed_filter' );

function wpa54142_filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '$today'";
    return $where;
}
```